# Аналог агрегирующего sql-запроса в Power BI

Tags: powerbi

В проекте Power BI есть таблица, содержащая список персон и числовой атрибут каждой персоны. Необходимо вывести гистограмму, показывающую количество персон по каждому значению атрибута. 
В sql вопрос решается элементарно - запрос с группировкой по параметру. А как подступиться к задаче в Power BI не пойму. Пните в нужном направлении.

Comment: Казалось бы, причем тут `excel` указанный в метке?

Comment: @Sublihim репутации на создание метки не хватило, а powerbi - это мутировавший excel power query

Answer (score 0):

- Бросаете на лист chart
- Перетаскиваете из числовой аттрибут в раздел Axis
- Перетаскиваете уникальный ключ (Name, например) в раздел Value

Получаете график с количеством людей по аттрибуту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, всё получилось!